# Google Maps makes the app stop Unfortunately

Tags: android, google-maps

We are working with an Android Application the first page is Splash screen and the later page is google map . This google map activity makes the app stop unfortunately in some android phones like android version 4.4.2. But in some android phone it is working fine . Is the google map has some restriction with the android API.

When it is run in Android version like 4.4.2 . It is showing this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{salon.com.barber/salon.com.barber.GoogleMapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at salon.com.barber.GoogleMapsActivity.populateMap(GoogleMapsActivity.java:287)
at salon.com.barber.GoogleMapsActivity.onCreate(GoogleMapsActivity.java:205)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5263)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
... 11 more
```

My Google Map Activity is

```
 public class GoogleMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

ImageButton imageButton;
NavDrawerListAdapterSalonDetails adapternav;
DrawerLayout dLayout;
List<NavDrawerSalonDetailsItem> menu;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ListView dList1;
private GoogleMap mMap;
GPSTracker gps;
boolean isGpsON;
ArrayList<String> arry_salondetails;
String SaloonDetails = "";
String Street = null;
String Zipcode = null;
String HouseNumber = null;
String City = null;
//final ArrayList<String> SalonNames = new ArrayList<String>();
final HashMap SalonData = new HashMap();

 double lati,longi;
final ArrayList<String> serviceDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
Boolean isInternetPresent;
JSONObject objectNextClass;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
JSONArray saloonDetails = null;
RelativeLayout selectedLayout;
double latitude, longitude, range;
String tableName = "barber";
Marker selectedMarker;
ImageButton button_bookmark ;
String objectId = "";
public static final String BARBER_MAP_PREFS = "MAP_PREFS";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);
    selectedLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.selectedView);


    networkCheck cd = new networkCheck(getApplicationContext());
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet(); // true or
    // false

    Log.i("sfeeee", "wwwwwww111w");




    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(BARBER_MAP_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String r = prefs.getString("range", null);
    if (r == null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putString("range", "10");
        editor.commit();
    }


    AndroidLog.appendLog("En:2");
    imageButton =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Search_btn);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        // On click function
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Create the intent to start another activity
            Log.i("sfeeee1111111", "wwwwwwww");
            Intent i = new Intent(GoogleMapsActivity.this, Search.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    AndroidLog.appendLog("Ex:2");


    dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    dList1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    menu = getNavDraweItemList();
    adapternav = new NavDrawerListAdapterSalonDetails(this, menu);
    LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
    View header=inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
    dList1.addHeaderView(header);
    dList1.setAdapter(adapternav);

    ImageButton buttonMenu =((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonMenu));

    dList1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            getListPosition(position);


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    buttonMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        // On click function
        public void onClick(View view) {

            dLayout.openDrawer(dList1);

        }
    });


    ImageButton  button_map=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_map);
    Log.i("111111111111111", "qqqqqqqqqqqqq");
    button_map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        // On click function
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Create the intent to start another activity

            if (isInternetPresent) {
                LatLng myCurrentLoc = getCurrentLoaction();
                Log.i("mycurrentLoc", myCurrentLoc.toString());
                Log.i("2222222222211", "qqqqqqqqqqqqq");
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        (myCurrentLoc), 11));
                Log.i("3333333333333331", "qqqqqqqqqqqqq");
            }
        }
    });



    AndroidLog.appendLog("En:3");
    if (isInternetPresent) {
        // Calling async task to get json
        //new getLocationData().execute();
        populateMap();
        AndroidLog.appendLog("Ex:3");
        Log.i("4444444411111", "qqqqqqqqqqqqq");
    } else {

        // Internet connection  not present
        // Ask user to connect to Internet
        showAlertDialog(GoogleMapsActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                "You don't have internet connection.", false);
    }



    selectedLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Button button = ((Button) selectedLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.selec_button_id));

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        // On click function
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Create the intent to start another activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                    Salon_Detail.class);

            //intent.putExtra("SalonName", (CharSequence) nameView);

            // intent.putExtra("json", objectNextClass.toString());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}




public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(BARBER_MAP_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.clear();

}





public void populateMap(){

    Log.d("searched", "map");

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GoogleMapsActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }

    LatLng myCurrentLoc = getCurrentLoaction();
    if(!isGpsON)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Switch on the location service for more  accuracy",
                30000).show();

    }
    Log.i("Latti and Longii", myCurrentLoc.toString());
    latitude = myCurrentLoc.latitude;
    Log.i("latitude of current Loc", String.valueOf(latitude));

    longitude = myCurrentLoc.longitude;
    Log.i("longitudeofcurrent Loc",String.valueOf(longitude));

   mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()

            .center(new LatLng(myCurrentLoc.latitude,
                    myCurrentLoc.longitude)).radius(10000)
            .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#34DDDD")).strokeWidth(6.0f)
                .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#93D5E4")));

    Log.i("777777777777777", "qqqqqqqqqqqqq");

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            (myCurrentLoc), 11));
    Log.i("666666666666666666", "qqqqqqqqqqqqq");
    Marker TP = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
            myCurrentLoc).title("").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.pin_blue)));
    //icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.navigate))

    TP.showInfoWindow();
    Log.i("5555555555555555555555", "qqqqqqqqqqqqq");
    TP.setSnippet("currentLocation");


    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(BARBER_MAP_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    range = Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString("range",null));


    //range = 100;




    new GmapUtil().onGetCustomMarkers(getApplicationContext(), longitude, latitude, range, tableName,
            new GmapUtil.CustomMarker() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String data) {
                    Log.i("resulttttttt od dataaa", data);
                    pDialog.hide();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                        Log.i("jsonObjectttttttttttt", jsonObject.toString());
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                        Log.i("jsonObjecttttttt1", jsonObject1.toString());
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("results");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            final JSONObject child = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            //final String sName = child.getString("SalonName");
                            //SalonNames.add(child.getString("SalonName"));
                            //Log.i("salonn namesss", SalonNames.toString());
                            latitude = child.getDouble("Latitude");
                            longitude = child.getDouble("Longitude");
                            LatLng saloonLoc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(saloonLoc).title("TutorialsPoint").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.map_red)));

                            marker.setSnippet(child.getString("objectId"));
                            SalonData.put(child.getString("objectId"), child);
                            Log.i("8888888888888888", "qqqqqqqqqqqqq");
                            // googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

                            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                                            SaloonDetails = "";
                                            // Take some action here
                                            String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
                                            objectId = snippet;

                                            if (selectedMarker != null && !("currentLocation".equals(snippet))) {
                                                selectedMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.map_red));

                                            }

                                            selectedMarker = marker;
                                            if (!("currentLocation".equals(snippet)))
                                                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.map_blue));


                                            Log.i("TAG", "snippet::::" + snippet);

                                            if ("currentLocation".equals(snippet)) {
                                                selectedLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                //button_bookmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                return false;
                                            } else {

                                                selectedLayout
                                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                                                TextView nameView = ((TextView) selectedLayout
                                                        .findViewById(R.id.name_txt_id));
                                                TextView addressView = ((TextView) selectedLayout
                                                        .findViewById(R.id.address_txt_id));



                                                try {
                                                    JSONObject jSalonData = (JSONObject)SalonData.get(snippet);

                                                    nameView.setText(jSalonData.getString("SalonName"));
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }


                                                try {
                                                    JSONObject jSalonData = (JSONObject)SalonData.get(snippet);
                                                    Log.i("jSalonData",jSalonData.toString());

                                                    //addressView.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                                    City = jSalonData.optString("City");
                                                    SaloonDetails = SaloonDetails + City;
                                                    Zipcode = jSalonData.optString("Zipcode");
                                                    SaloonDetails = SaloonDetails  +" "+ Zipcode;
                                                    HouseNumber = jSalonData.optString("HouseNumber");
                                                    SaloonDetails = SaloonDetails  +" "+ HouseNumber;
                                                    Street = jSalonData.optString("Street");
                                                    SaloonDetails = SaloonDetails +" "+ Street;
                                                    Log.i("SaloonDetails", SaloonDetails);
                                                    //addressView.setText(jSalonData.getString("Zipcode"));
                                                    //addressView.setText(jSalonData.getString("City"));
                                                    addressView.setText(SaloonDetails);

                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                                return true;
                                            }
                                        }

                                    });

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("Exception", e.toString());
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String data) {

                }
            });

}



private LatLng getCurrentLoaction() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("sfeeee","wwwwwwww");
    gps = new GPSTracker(GoogleMapsActivity.this);

    // check if GPS enabled
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        isGpsON=true;
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        Log.i("Latiiiiiiiiii",latLng.toString());
        return latLng;
        // \n is for new line
    } else {
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        isGpsON=false;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(52.156111,5.387827);
        return latLng;

    }

}

private List<NavDrawerSalonDetailsItem> getNavDraweItemList() {


    String search = "Search";
    String Privacypolicy = "Privacy policy";
    String termsofconditions = "Terms and Conditions";
    String favorite = " Favourites";
    String Setting = "Settings";

    String[] list = new String[] {search, Privacypolicy,termsofconditions,favorite,Setting};
    int[] icons = { R.mipmap.small_search, R.mipmap.small_about_us };
    List<NavDrawerSalonDetailsItem> menu = new ArrayList<NavDrawerSalonDetailsItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        menu.add(new NavDrawerSalonDetailsItem(list[i], i));
    }

    return menu;
}





/**
 * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
 *
 * @param context
 *            - application context
 * @param title
 *            - alert dialog title
 * @param message
 *            - alert message
 * @param status
 *            - success/failure (used to set icon)
 * */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
                            Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {

        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}


public void search(){

    // Create the intent to start another activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(GoogleMapsActivity.this, Search.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}

public void privacyPolicy(){


    // Create the intent to start another activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(GoogleMapsActivity.this, privacypolicy.class);

    startActivity(intent);

}

public void termsAndCondition(){


    // Create the intent to start another activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(GoogleMapsActivity.this, Terms_and_condition.class);

    startActivity(intent);

}

public void favorite(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(GoogleMapsActivity.this,comingsoon.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void Settings(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(GoogleMapsActivity.this,comingsoon.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}




public void getListPosition(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 1: {

            search();

            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            privacyPolicy();
            break;
        }
       case 3: {
            termsAndCondition();
            break;
        }
         case 4: {
            favorite();

            break;
        }
       case 5: {

            Settings();
            break;
        }
        default: {

            break;
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: add your code incuding populateMap() method

Comment: you need to include the part of the code too where its is giving that exception

Comment: which is the line 287?

Comment: mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()

                .center(new LatLng(myCurrentLoc.latitude,
                        myCurrentLoc.longitude)).radius(10000)
                .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#34DDDD")).strokeWidth(6.0f)
                    .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#93D5E4")));

Comment: The mMap is showing the  problem. it is not instantiated in some phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that you are using a non-null instance of GoogleMap you should implement OnMapReadyCallback. From the documentation https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback

> Once an instance of this interface is set on a MapFragment or MapView object, the onMapReady(GoogleMap) method is triggered when the map is ready to be used and provides a non-null instance of GoogleMap.:

So, your `GoogleMapsActivity` needs to implement `OnMapReadyCallback` and you have to move the call your `populateMap();` method to the `onMapReady` method:

```
public class GoogleMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    // ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Remove populateMap(); and change it for
        ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        populateMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the devices the map is ready or not when you are trying to use it using `((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`, but according to https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment "A `GoogleMap` must be acquired using `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)`"

Comment: The map is coming in all the phone without crashing the phone . But the populate map function is not working because the control is not coming into the onMapReady function.Inside the populatemap function all the codes are implemented so that nothing is coming

Comment: Have you added the `getMapAsync` call to the `onCreate` method? Do you see the map and can you zoom in/out?

Comment: Did this answer finally solve your problem? If so, consider marking it as the accepted answer